# How do I check for the existence of a file using a wildcard in Bourne shell?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
if [ -f "filenam*" ]; then
   ...
fi
```

But the wildcard (*) causes problems.

I've also tried:

```
if [ `ls filenam* > /dev/null 2>&1` ]; then
   ...
fi
```

Which may work in other shells but doesn't appear to work in Bourne shell (sh).

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Sorry, not C shell, Bourne shell (sh).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion everyone.  I meant Bourne shell rather than C shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `test -n $(ls filenam*)`, you might prefer:

```
if ls filenam* 2> /dev/null | grep . > /dev/null; then
   ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is C based, you probably need the glob command:

```
ls `glob filenam*`
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. Try this:

```
if [ ! -z `ls filenam*` ] ; then
    ...
fi
```

That will check whether ls returns anything.

Comment: if [ ! -z `ls filenam* > /dev/null 2>&1` ]; then ... gives me the error "test: argument expected".  Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than ! -z, you can use -n

Comment: I thought you were using a normal shell. I didn't realize how broken csh is. I tried using a tutorial to figure this out, and I still couldn't get it to work using any logical construct. There does not seem to be a way to execute ls and look at its output.

Answer (score 0):

As this is csh, what about:

```
foreach i (`ls -d filenam*`)
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this:

```
function first() { echo "$1" ; }
[ -e $(first filenam*) ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```